# Whose responsibility are Python exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

Let's say I'm using a Python library, like `requests`.
`requests` has a list of exceptions you are expected to handle: https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#exceptions

Internally, `requests` uses the `urllib3` library. `urllib3` might use the `socket` library, which has its own list of exceptions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#exceptions

If I'm using the `requests` library, do I need to be worried about catching exceptions thrown by the `socket` library, like `socket.timeout`? Or is the list of `requests` exceptions in my first hyperlink a promise by them that they will handle all lower-level exceptions, and the only ones I should see are the ones on that list of `requests` exceptions?

If I'm using `requests`, and a `socket.timeout` exception is thrown, should I be reporting that as a bug to `requests`?

Comment: If I'm writing Python software, I don't want to find out about the possibility of an undocumented exception during runtime. At that point, the code might be passed the testing stages (where the exception was never thrown by the library), and in production. I also don't want to be digging through every single library I use (could be dozens of libraries), and every single library they use, to find out every possible exception that might be thrown. The only safe course of action seems to be to catch all exceptions, and classify them as expected, or not expected.

Answer (score 0):

You are ultimately responsible for uncaught exceptions if you don't want your program to be terminated by one.

That said, it could not hurt to file a `socket.timeout` as a bug. Either it *is* a bug, or the documentation can be updated to clarify that such an exception is possible. Without looking at the code, the existence of `requests.Timeout` suggests that it would be a bug.

Comment: Sounds like that literally means you have 3 choices: a) catch only the exceptions the library mentions, and risk your program crashing if they didn't list/catch one, b) a multi-block `try` statement that catches all exceptions you expect, and a `except Exception:` as a last resort, or just a `try:... except Exception as ex:...` block where you test the type of exception you caught, and deal with expected exceptions, and unexpected exceptions